Definiton of wild ramification group and isomorphism $\Delta \cong \prod_{s \neq \ell} \mathbb{Z}_s(1)$
This is a question regarding proof Theorem $1.4$ of https://kskedlaya.org/kolyvagin-seminar/duality.pdf
The pdf states the following about what is considered a well-known fact.
Let $K$ be a local field and $\mathcal{I}$ be inertia group.

Let $\Delta$ be the image of $\mathcal{I}$ in the tamely ramified part
of absolute Galois group $G_K$, i.e.
$0 \to \mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{I} \to \Delta \to 0 $
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the wild-ramification group which is a rather
complicated group. On the other hand it is well-known that $\Delta
 \cong \prod_{s \neq \ell} \mathbb{Z}_s(1)$.

May I ask two questions regarding the above ?
$(1)$What is the definiiton of $\mathcal{P}$ in this context ?
$(2)$Do you have some refference on the isomorphism $\Delta
 \cong \prod_{s \neq \ell} \mathbb{Z}_s(1)$?
These may be common knowledge to those who are accustomed to number theory, but for me, they are new definitions and unclear facts, and I have been unable to find relevant references or websites. I would appreciate any suggestions for sites or literature. Thank you very much.

Let $K^{tm}$ be the maximal tame extension of $K$; this is the compositum of all finite extensions of $K$ such that $p$ does not divide the ramification degree. Then $\mathcal{P}$ (the wild inertia group) is the Galois group of $\overline{K}$ over $K^{tm}$. It is (obviously) a subgroup of the Galois group of $\overline{K}$ over the maximal unramified extension $K^{ur}$ since the ramification degree of an unramified extension is $1$. For the computation of $\Delta$, read the first section in the chapter in Serre's book on local fields about higher ramification groups (this is the $\Delta$ for a finite extension and then you have to take a limit).
